# how do I parse out this URL-encoded string with a JSON array using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, json, urlencode, mandrill

When I use a webhook with Mandrill and post to my Iron Worker, I get the following Raw (this is from RequestBin, as well) -- I didn't include the whole payload, just an example:

`puts payload =>`

```
mandrill_events=%5B%7B%22event%22%3A%22inbound%22%2C%22msg%22%3A%7B%22dkim%22%3A%7B%22signed%22%3Atrue%2C%22valid%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22email%22%3A%22kaya%40hellokaya.com%22%2C%22from_email%22%3A%22example.sender%40mandrillapp.com%22%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%22Content-Type%22%3A%22multipart%5C%2Falternative%3B+boundary%3D%5C%22_av-7r7zDhHxVEAo2yMWasfuFw%5C%22%22%2C%22Date%22%3A%22Fri%2C+10+May+2013+19%3A28%3A20+%2B0000%22%2C%22Dkim-Signature%22%3A%5B%22v%3D1%3B+a%3Drsa-
```

I tried to extract the value of the parameter `mandrill_events` using:

`puts params = CGI::parse(@payload) =>`

```
{"mandrill_events"=>["[{\"event\":\"inbound\",\"msg\":{\"dkim\":{\"signed\":true,\"valid\":true},\"email\":\"kaya@hellokaya.com\",\"from_email\":\"example.sender@mandrillapp.com\",\"headers\":{\"Content-Type\":\"multipart\\/alternative; boundary=\\\"_av-7r7zDhHxVEAo2yMWasfuFw\\\"\",\"Date\":\"Fri, 10 May 2013 19:28:20 +0000\",\"Dkim-Signature\":[\"v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed\\/relaxed; s=mandrill; d=mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com; h=From:Sender:Subject:List-Unsubscribe:To:Message-Id:Date:MIME-Version:Content-Type; i=example.sender@mail115.us4.mandrillapp.com;
```

Then I am stuck.  I want to extract the email value in the JSON.array.

I thought to try the following;

`puts json_params = JSON.parse(params)`

But I am now feeling there must be a better way....

**How can I extract the elements from the JSON array in this URL-encoded string?**

Comment: what is the problem with current solution?

Comment: the `params` value isn't valid JSON, can you check it again please.

Comment: We can't help you without valid data. The JSON isn't correct. If that is *really* how the data comes to you, then you'll need to write code to strip off the stuff that makes the JSON invalid, then parse the resulting string and the rest should be easy.

Comment: If you just want the email you can do it with a regex: `CGI.unescape(payload)[/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i]`

Comment: Yes, it's not straightforward JSON.  I will update what the outcome turns out to be....